# The inverse of a linear transformation $A$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose that $A$ is a non-singular linear transformation of an $n$-dimensional linear space into itself. Show that there exists some polynomial $c_0+c_1z+\ldots+c_kz^k$ so that
$$A^{-1}=c_0I+c_1A+\ldots+c_kA^k.$$

---

We only have to show that $c_kA^{k+1}+\ldots+c_0A-I=0.$

On the other hand, according to Hamilton-Cayley Theorem, $A$ satisfy the characteristic polynomial, that is, $f(A)=0,$ where $f(\cdot)$ is the characteristic polynomial. But how do we know that the constant term of the polynomial is $-I?$

Comment: Try to come up with more descriptive titles in the future.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(A) = c_nA^n + \cdots + c_1A+c_0I = 0$, then $-\dfrac{c_n}{c_0}A^n - \cdots - \dfrac{c_1}{c_0}A-I = 0$.

Since $A$ is non-singular, we have $\det A \neq 0$, and so $c_0 \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

One needn't use the theorem of Hamilton Cayley. Suppose your vector space has dimension $n>1$. The set $\{1,A,\ldots,A^{n^2-1}\}$ cannot be linearly independent, since for $n>1$, the ring of matrices of size $n\times n$ is not commutative. Thus we have a polynomial, which we may assume is monic, that kills $A$. We may take it to be of minimum degree. Let's say it is $$m_A=x^m-a_1x^{m-1}-\cdots-a_m$$

Since $A$ is invertible, $a_m=0$ would give us a polynomial of lesser degree that vanishes at $A$. Hence $a_n\neq 0$; and we may obtain the inverse of $A$ as a polynomial in $A$.